# Overlay "Structured Glas" Effect on iPhone Camera Feed - General Directions

Tags: iphone, image-processing, filtering, video-processing

I'm currently trying to write an app, that would be able to show the effects of glas, as seen through the iPhone Camera.
I'm not talking about simple, uniform glas but glass like this:
[image: Glas Image]

Now I already broke this into two problems:

1) Apply some Image Filter to the 2D-frames presented by the iPhone Camera. This has been done and seems possible, e.g. in the app: [faceman](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/faceman/id388888160?mt=8)

2) I need to get the individual lighting properties of a sheet of glas that my client supplies me with. Now basicly, there must be a way to read the information about how the glas distorts ands skews the image. I think It might be somehow possible to make a high-res picture of the plate of glasplate, laid on a checkerboard-image and somehow analyze this.

Now, I'm mostly searching for literature, weblinks on how you guys think I could start at 2. It doesn't need to be exact, in the end I just need something that looks approximately like the sheet of glass I want to show. And I'm don't even know where to search, Physics, Image Filtering or Comupational Photography books.

EDIT: I'm currently thinking, that one easy solution could be bump-mapping the texture on top of the camera-feed, I asked another question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273946/bump-mapping-on-top-if-iphone-camera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add that I solved this old answer using [the refraction example in the Khronos OpenGl ES SDK](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp).

Wrote a blog-entry with pictures about it :

[simulating windows with refraction](http://tacticadev.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/simulating-windows-with-refraction/)

[image: refracted image]
[image: clear image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with OpenGL. You want to effectively have a texture - similar to the one you've got above - displace the texture below it (the live camera view) to give the impression of depth and distortion. This is a 'non-trivial' problem, in that whilst it's a fairly standard problem in its field if you're coming from a background with no graphics or OpenGL experience you can expect a very steep learning curve.

So in short, the only way you can achieve this realistically on iOS is to use OpenGL, and that should be your starting point. Apple have a few guides on the matter, but you'll be better off looking elsewhere. There are some useful books such as the OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide that can get you off on the right track, but where you start would depend on how comfortable you are with 3D graphics and C.

Comment: I know OpenGL, but I really don't think 3D-textures would help. From a mathematical standpoint this is a filtering issue, where I need to modify pixels in a 2D-Image A to form a new 2D-Image B. Anyway the main question is about the issue B) , not A). (And B doesn't have anything to do with OpenGL)

Comment: You're making the mistake of assuming OpenGL is 3D graphics only. It isn't. It's the *only way to achieve high performance texture work on iOS*. You won't be able to achieve this using Core Graphics, or any non-Open GL graphics API on iOS, because nothing is fast enough. Core Image isn't supported, so you can't use a Core Image filter. OpenGL solves both parts of your question. The second part of your question isn't really relevant to iOS, but what you'd do is exactly the same method you'd use for determining lens distortion on a camera.

Comment: Sorry, I think we misunderstood each other. I said I'm don't think 3D would help, but didn't mean i'm not using OpenGL. The Thing is that I know OpenGL, it's just that I don't know where to get an algorithm that reads the information of the glas.